# Images are not being saved in my camera app

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-sdcard, android-image

I'm trying to make an app that detects motion and takes picture when the motion is detected. Its saving the picture when I don't try to save it in the directory(folder). But when I try it with the directory, the picture is not being saved even though the directory is being created successfully.
What changes should I make to the following code in order to make it work:

```
 private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(String name, Bitmap bitmap) {

        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
            File.separator + "XYX APP");
             boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdirs();
    }
        if (success) {
        // Do something on success

    } else {
        // Do something else on failure
    }

        File photo = new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"XYZ APP/"), name+ ".jpg");
        if (photo.exists()) {
            photo.delete();
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Note: The file name is generated in the following instruction:**

```
 String name = "MotDet_"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
            if (bitmap != null) createDirectoryAndSaveFile(name, bitmap);
```

**Update**
It works with the following code but not with the code above :

```
    private void save(String name, Bitmap bitmap) {
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), name + ".jpg");
        if (photo.exists()) photo.delete();

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you testing in marshmello?

Comment: @Jayanth      Yes on s7 edge

Comment: @Jayanth Did you see my updated question? It works with that code but not when I try making the directory

Comment: try replacing line File photo = new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"XYZ APP/"), name+ ".jpg");
with the line in my answer

Comment: with this line File photo = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath()+"/XYZ APP/"+ name+ ".jpg");

Comment: and make sure your name variable does not ends with .jpg

Comment: @Jayanth It worked ... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: you can even thank me by accepting the answer :)

Comment: @Jayanth Sure .. But please edit your answer. The correct one u gave is in these comments not on your current answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you missed the FileSeperator before xyz

```
 File photo = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath()+"/XYZ APP/"+ name+ ".jpg");
```

And your Function becomes

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(String name, Bitmap bitmap) {

File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
        File.separator + "XYZ APP");//here you have created different name
boolean success = true;
if (!folder.exists()) {
    success = folder.mkdirs();
}
if (success) {
    // Do something on success

} else {
    // Do something else on failure
}

File photo = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath(), name+ ".jpg"); 
if (photo.exists()) {
    photo.delete();
}
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Marshmello comes with RuntimePermissions in order for you to save file in external directory you need to ask permission first, like below code

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    } else {

        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        return false;
    }
}
else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
    Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
    return true;
}
```

}

permission result callback

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
      super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
       if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
          Log.v(TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
          //resume tasks needing this permission
      }
   }
```

before saving call `isStoragePermissionsGranted()` if it returns `true` proceed saving file.

Comment: In fact I try it with API 22. It saves the file when I try do it in the root of the sd card. but it doesn't when I try it in the folder.

Comment: you missed File seperator '/' before XYZ try adding it

Comment: I tried adding the file separator. its still not saving. :(

Comment: I don't see it bro.. the absolutepath line is not in your answer, its is in comments

Comment: have you seen this question of mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798795/how-to-create-a-layout-on-top-of-my-camera-surfaceview

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
String partFilename = currentDateFormat();
storeCameraPhotoInSDCard(bp, partFilename);

private String currentDateFormat(){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss");
        String  currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        return currentTimeStamp;
    }

private void storeCameraPhotoInSDCard(Bitmap bitmap, String currentDate){
        File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo_" + currentDate + ".jpg");
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This code is work for me..Save image to directory.

Comment: I want to save the file inside a folder in the SD Card, not in the root of SD Card

Comment: Have you seen this question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798795/how-to-create-a-layout-on-top-of-my-camera-surfaceview

Answer (score 0):

You have to get `permission` of external storage at run time in `android 6.0` and above to write in SDCard

Read [Run time Permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

add in **manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**replace your function with below one**

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(String name, Bitmap bitmap) {

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
            File.separator + "XYZ APP");//here you have created different name
    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {
        // Do something on success

    } else {
        // Do something else on failure
    }

    File photo = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath(), name+ ".jpg"); //use path of above created folder
    if (photo.exists()) {
        photo.delete();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done that. It saves the file when I try do it in the root of the sd card. but it doesn't when I try it in the folder

Comment: you forgot separator here `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"XYZ APP/"), name+ ".jpg")`

Comment: I tried adding the file separator. its still not saving. :(

Comment: Have you seen this question of mine  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798795/how-to-create-a-layout-on-top-of-my-camera-surfaceview  ?